# How do I implement a checkbox list in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist

Just moved from WebForms to MVC and replacing various userinterfaces. Not sure how the WebForms CheckListBox is implemented, is there a jQuery plugin or a basic example of this somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your need for jQuery, a template similar to this is what I routinely use. (You should be able to wire up jQuery events to this; I'm keeping this to a basic template for now.)

```
<div class="checkBoxList"><!-- This class usually defines a max-height and overflow -->
    <% foreach (MyObject o in Model.MyObjects) { %>
        <input type="checkbox" name="myObjectSelections" 
            value="<%=o.Value%>" /><br />
        <%=o.Text%>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

(I may refine this answer in a couple hours once I'm at work and see my real code for this, but it should get you started.)

Your action method for this will take an array of `bool`s for the `myObjectSelections` argument.

Comment: @John Rudy: Thats Great I thought it may just be checkboxes within a scrollable div...